# Qlikview - show first and last selected value in list

Tags: max, min, qlikview

I need to display first and last selected value in list. I have listbox and when I pick date I got this result in list

[image]

I want to get in one box min value selected but when I use minString(Data) I got 22/2022 instead 303/202. And for max I need to get 306/2022.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: It looks like 303/2022 is excluded based on your selections. Are you looking for the minimum value which is excluded based on current selections?

Answer (score 0):

To get the Qlik engine to ignore the selected values you need to set analysis.

Firstly, you should be using a max() not a maxstring(). Max() will evaluate the maximum numerical value. Maxstring() will evaluate the maximum ascii values of the string (I think, anyone can correct me).

Secondly, the value 306/2022 in that list is grey which means it is no longer included in the dataset used for the visualisations being displayed. The white values are the values that are included, this is why min(Date) is returing 22/2022. 22/2022 is the minimum available (white) value in that list. 303/2022 is the minimum value of the excluded values in grey.

If you want to be able to reference the values even when the selections have caused it to be excluded (turned them grey) you need to modify your max() to max({1}).

{1} means look at all the data not just the selected data.

```
max({1} Date)
```

will return 306/2022 no matter what the selections are.

If you want to return 303/2022. The minimum of the excluded values and have that change dynamically when making other selections let me know and I can show you but I will require you to explain why you would want to that before I try figure it out :)

Comment: When I put this =max({1} invoice)  nothing is happening

Comment: The point of the {1} is that the displayed value will not change when you make selections. I don't think I understand what you are trying to achieve here

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the OnOpen document trigger.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kirph.png)

Comment: This makes no sense

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).